# How can I render floating text in a website?

Tags: javascript, html, webgl, particles, particles.js

My objective is to make some floating words **as if it were paper floating on water**.
I can't find any library that does that or any project on github/youtube.

It should be similar to the particles.js movement but rotating randomly and a lot slower, as I said, as if it were paper on the sea.

**Particles.js example video:** https://wearcontour.com/cosillas/particles.mp4 (ignore the lag).

I've tried to edit the particles.js library to do this but I can't find a solution.

This is the **particles.js** main file.

```
      case 'circle':
        pJS.canvas.ctx.arc(p.x, p.y, radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
      break;
      
      case 'text':
        Text("lorem ipsum");
      break;

      case 'edge':
        pJS.canvas.ctx.rect(p.x-radius, p.y-radius, radius*2, radius*2);
      break;

      case 'triangle':
        pJS.fn.vendors.drawShape(pJS.canvas.ctx, p.x-radius, p.y+radius / 1.66, radius*2, 3, 2);
      break;

      case 'polygon':
        pJS.fn.vendors.drawShape(
          pJS.canvas.ctx,
          p.x - radius / (pJS.particles.shape.polygon.nb_sides/3.5), // startX
          p.y - radius / (2.66/3.5), // startY
          radius*2.66 / (pJS.particles.shape.polygon.nb_sides/3), // sideLength
          pJS.particles.shape.polygon.nb_sides, // sideCountNumerator
          1 // sideCountDenominator
        );
      break;

      case 'image':

        function draw(){
          pJS.canvas.ctx.drawImage(
            img_obj,
            p.x-radius,
            p.y-radius,
            radius*2,
            radius*2 / p.img.ratio
          );
        }

        if(pJS.tmp.img_type == 'svg'){
          var img_obj = p.img.obj;
        }else{
          var img_obj = pJS.tmp.img_obj;
        }

        if(img_obj){
          draw();
        }

      break;
```

The `case 'text'` part is the thing I added, but obviously it doesn't work.
When I modify the app config file (shown below) typing `text` instead of `circle` in the "shape" part, the nodes simply don't display.

Config file:

```
      "shape": {
        "type": "circle",
        "stroke": {
          "width": 0,
          "color": "#000000"
        },
```

I don't know how to solve this. If you know how to modify the library or you just know another way to help me, let me know.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Something like this? https://codepen.io/matteobruni/pen/xxGdyjd

Comment: @Caelan yeah, it's simillar to my idea, but with words instead of characters and without them leaving the canvas. Thanks ;)

Comment: https://codepen.io/matteobruni/pen/abdwNgv this should be what you need

Comment: @Caelan Kinda! Many thanks buddy, I'll modify it a bit with your permission and use it in a project. I'll credit you :)

Comment: If you make changes to tsParticles feel free to submit a PR, the pen is just a sample, you can modify it as you want

Comment: @Caelan Of course. But now I'm having trouble exporting the pen to my machine. How should I export it with the dependencies? I can't find any tutorial and linking with `<script src="foo.bar/tsparticles.min.js">` in the html does nothing. Nothing appears on the screen.

Sorry for my lack of knowledge, I practically never used codepen.

Comment: Checkout github.com/matteobruni/tsparticles this is the particles library, in the readme there are all the instructions you need. Then just include the script and copy all the script pane from codepen to your javascript

Comment: @Caelan Would it be possible to somehow make the texts clickable?

Comment: Not for easily for the moment, if you open an issue I can tell you more